# How can I prevent Windows update from installing updates at restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I see on `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update`:

[image]

I don't want any Windows update to be installed. How can I  prevent  Windows update  from  installing updates at restart?

[image]

---

I have  since then disabled  Windows update:

[image]

and  in `cmd.exe`  I have executed `wusa /uninstall /kb:<kbnumber>`  for each  Windows update  that was recently installed.  Is that enough? ( I haven't restarted the computer yet)

---

Output of  [WhyReboot](http://exodusdev.com/products/whyreboot):

[image]

Output of  [WMI VBScript written by Tom Mills](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tommills/2008/08/15/a-handy-wmi-script-to-check-for-pending-file-rename-operations/)

[image]

Script is as follows (save as a `.vbs` file):

```
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
'Name:   CheckPendingFileRenameOperations
'Programmer: Tom Mills/Microsoft Corp.
'Date:  8/14/2008
'Purpose: Checks registry key for pending file rename operations
'Notes:  None
'---------------------------------------------------------------------


CONST HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002


strComputer = "."
strFileOps = ""


Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"&_ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")


strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"


strValueName = "PendingFileRenameOperations"


Return = objReg.GetMultiStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,_
    strValueName,arrValues)


If (Return = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then   
    For Each strValue In arrValues
    strFileOps = strFileOps & chr(13) & strValue
Next


    WScript.Echo "Pending File Rename Operations Found: " & strFileOps


Else
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
         Wscript.Echo "No Pending File Operations Found"
    Else
         Wscript.Echo "Check Pending File Operations failed. Error = " & Err.Number
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Everything it's showing to be done on reboot is simply cleanup of tasks that have already run and their executables are no longer needed.

Comment: BTW, the reboot isn't just for file cleanup.  Changes can be made to the stored version of files (including the kernel or other OS files), but that doesn't affect what's currently running.  You won't know if the update created a problem until you reboot and the new stuff is loaded.